# Is there a way to automate a sequence of commands in the command line or create some sort of shortcut?

Tags: git, cmd

I would like to know if there is a shortcut when it comes to entering a set of commands into the command line.

If someone had to repeatedly enter 4 commands ( i.e `git add .` , `git commit`, `git push`, and `git pull`) into the command-line, is there any way this process can be sped up?

For example, using only one line as some sort of shortcut?
Any help is truly appreciated.

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to achieve. Most of the times aliases work. If your steps are lengthy, create a shell script and add the execution cmd to your alias

Comment: create some bash script with optional parameters(from stdin) is an option.

Comment: There's a reason to these different commands. What do you do if one of them fails? Can you even detect that? This sort of automation seems like a great way to shoot yourself (and potentially others) in the foot.

Comment: @JanWilamowski That is why, in the last example I give in the answer, I propose to chain those commands with `&&`: the first one failing will stop the all set.

Comment: @VonC that's a start but I think there are more subtle problems like the lack of manual reviewing. I rarely ever add & commit all local changes into a single revision and I always go through the change set, often finding issues with it. People (especially beginners) should be aware of these downsides for the sake of short-term convenience.

Comment: @JanWilamowski I fully agree, any alias is not always a good idea, and should not obfuscate good practices. Still, I find them so convenient from time to time ;)

Comment: As you have used the [[tag:cmd]] tag, for the Windows Command Prompt, _(`cmd.exe`)_, what is wrong with just using the `[▲]` and `[▼]` keys, along with the `↵`/`[ENTER]` key. **_It cycles through your previous commands_**.

Answer (score 3):

[`git alias`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases) is can [`execute functions`](https://www.atlassian.com/blog/git/advanced-git-aliases)

```
my_alias = "!f() { 〈your complex command〉 }; f"
```

But if this is not enough, see also "[**Powerful Git Macros For Automating Everyday Workflows**](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/powerful-git-macros-for-automating-everyday-workflows)" from **[Wil Hall](https://twitter.com/alphapneumatic)**

Wil proposes:

- glt aliases and git alias functions
- shell aliases
- GitHub from command line with [`gh` (`cli/cli`)](https://github.com/cli/cli), previously [`hub`](https://hub.github.com/)

> For example, I might branch `feature` off of `develop` and make two commits, and now I want to squash those two commits.
> I could run `git rebase -i HEAD~2`, or we can build a macro that works for any number of commits and any action so that you don’t have to go hunting for the commit you’re looking for on your branch.
>
> I call this function `gbir` (`git-branch-interactive-rebase`):
>
> ```sh
> gbir() {
>  git rebase -i --autosquash $(git merge-base --fork-point "$@" $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD))
> }
> ```

In your case, for a complex suite of commands, a shell alias (that you are [sourcing](https://opensource.com/article/20/6/bash-source-command)) is a better fit:

> Let’s look at incorporating changes from a base branch `develop` into a `feature` branch feature.
> We want to make sure we have the latest changes from both the base branch and our `feature` branch, and then we want to perform the rebase.
> Let’s call it `gqrb` (`git-quick-rebase`):
>
> ```sh
> gqrb() {
>    git set-upstream
>    git fetch origin "$@:$@" && git pull && git rebase "$@"
> }
> ```
>
> Now with `feature` checked out, we can run `gqrb develop` to incorporate changes from `develop` into `feature`.
>
> Firstly we run `git set-upstream` because this will fail if we don’t have an upstream branch.
> Next, we run `git fetch` for only the `develop` branch.
> Then we pull the current branch (`feature`).
> And finally, we run `git rebase develop`.
>
> If any of those steps fails, `&&` will stop execution of the subsequent commands.